# How to add placeholder in the select tag in angular Typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, select, placeholder

I'm trying to use a placeholder for dropdowns in the select tag, but the placeholder isn't working. Also, I tried some other options, but they didn't work.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Category" required placeholder="Category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select one category </option>
    <option *ngFor="let data of array" [value]="data.Value">{{data.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have a select tag where I remove the  **[(ngModel)]="Category"**  properties and it shows the placeholder option, but when I add them it shows Blank in Placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

**In TS File declare your [(ngModel)] as null, it will work,
I have attached the stackblitz demo as well.**

You can use an option with disabled.

In **TS**:

```
selected4 = null;
```

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected4">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">Hey</option>
    <option value="2">Hello</option>
</select>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-placeholder-tqtumk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :), `<option [ngValue]="undefined" [disabled]="true">-- Select Value --</option>` It working fine.